# How to add elements to a list from chome.storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

With localStorage I can just do like:

```
let words;

if (localStorage.getItem('words') === null) {
    words = [];
} else {
    words = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('words'));
}
```

What I tried so far:

```
function logBytes(bytes) {
    return bytes;
}
chrome.storage.local.getBytesInUse(['words'], logBytes);
    if (logBytes === 0) {
        words = [];
        log(logBytes(bytes));
    }
     } else {
         words = JSON.parse(chrome.storage.local.get('words')), function () {
             
         };
     }
```

How can I do it with chome.storage set and get?

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage stores the values as a string so in order to store your array you have to convert it into string with `JSON.stringify(array_name)`

And when retrieving the data you have to parse it with `JSON.parse("key")`

for example

```
var arr = ['cat','mouse'];
localStorage.setItem("myArr",JSON.stringify("arr"));

//And to retrive the data
var myLocalArr = localStorage.getItem("myArr");
var myLocalArr = JSON.parse(myLocalArr);
console.log(myLocalArr) // result -> ["cat","mouse"]
```